# ?? how to get stored procedure return value using enterprise library 6?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, return-value, enterprise-library

---------- sproc code ----------------------------

```
CREATE proc dbo.[usp_UpsertCustomer] 
@CustomerID int, @CustomerName nvarchar(50), @CustomerAddress nvarchar(100),
@CustomerPhone nvarchar(50), @CustomerEmail nvarchar(50)
as
set nocount on
declare @initcount int = (select count(*) from dbo.Customer)
begin
merge dbo.Customer as c
using (select @CustomerID,@CustomerName,@CustomerAddress,@CustomerPhone,@CustomerEmail) as s
-- src data maps to the following fields
              (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerPhone, CustomerEmail)
on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
when matched then --update the record
    update set c.CustomerName = s.CustomerName, c.CustomerAddress = s.CustomerAddress,
               c.CustomerPhone = s.CustomerPhone, c.CustomerEmail = s.CustomerEmail
when not matched then --insert the new record
    insert (CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerPhone,CustomerEmail)
    values (s.CustomerName,s.CustomerAddress,s.CustomerPhone,s.CustomerEmail);

-- return ID of the new record if created
if @initcount < (select count(*) from dbo.Customer)
    return (select max(CustomerID) from dbo.Customer)
else
    return 0
end
```

--------- c# code -------------------------

```
public class clsAutoInvoiceDb
{
    private Database objDb = new DatabaseProviderFactory().CreateDefault();
    public int CreateCustomer(string _CustomerName, string _CustomerAddress, 
                              string _CustomerPhone, string _CustomerEmail)
    {
        DbCommand cmd = objDb.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_UpsertCustomer");
        objDb.AddParameter(cmd, "@return_value", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, null, DataRowVersion.Default, null);
        objDb.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_UpsertCustomer", -1, _CustomerName, _CustomerAddress, _CustomerPhone, _CustomerEmail);

        return Convert.ToInt32(objDb.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@return_value"));
```

--------- my problem/question -----------------

insert is always successful, yet @return_value is null when the return statement executes.  life was good with this code segment before I refactored to use entlib. now can't get my return value.  anyone have any ideas?  have wasted 3+ hours on this already.

Comment: I can see a few problems with your sproc, 'working' or not.

Comment: enlighten me please.  famously, the sproc "works fine on my machine." problem is in the objDb.ExecuteNonQuery. when i use the(sprocname + params[]) overload, return_value never gets populated with the CustomerID.  when i use objDb.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd), works fine. however, to use ...(cmd) requires adding the param values one-by-one using objDb.AddInParameter. i much prefer the 1-line ...(sproc,params[]) overload, but alas, doesn't return the return_value

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on your question and I share the same pain.

I've tried what posts suggests however it does not work and there is limited official guidance in this direction.

However as a workaround I've gotten this to work ( brickbats welcome...-) )

1. In sql instead of **return** use **select** to return value. So in your case do this
   `if @initcount < (select count(*) from dbo.Customer)
   select max(CustomerID) from dbo.Customer
   else
   select 0
   end`
2. And in c# do this

`var returnValue = db.ExecuteScalar("usp_UpsertCustomer",parameterArray);`

Hope it helps you and other fellow enterprise library data access block users.